# CreateJS: mask in the browser Opera 47

Tags: opera, mask, createjs

After the update Opera, ceased to work correctly the mask. The example in the picture: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tNby.png)
Am I doing something wrong or have a problem of the browser?
Thank you.

Comment: Any chance you can post a snippet of the generated lib code?

Comment: Tested the CreateJS mask API in the latest Opera (version 47.0.2631.71 on OS X Sierra 10.12.6) and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2j78kmob/

Comment: Opera 47.0.2631.71 + Windows 7 (two different desktop): example does not work. White canvas. But it is interesting, that the mask is working again in the browser Opera 49.0.2695.0 (Opera developer).

Comment: If it started working again in Opera developer, then good chance it is a browser bug. EaselJS just proxies the canvas APIs, so it was probably an issue introduced to Canvas, which was then fixed.

Comment: Tested in Opera (47.0.2631.48) on Windows 7 with no issue. Could be a very specific revision of Opera

Comment: Thank you very much. Probably, bug in the Opera browser 47.0.2631.71, but in this browser the clipping works correctly. I hope Opera will soon be updated. Thanks again.